# Javascript - Accessing a global array in a DOM event

Tags: javascript, arrays, event-listener

I'm currently working on a links generator in order to improve myself. I've had trouble accessing a global array declared at the beginning of my script inside a "click" event since day one. I've tried to debug it myself but am stuck!

Currently I'm trying to add new data from a form at the beginning of the array with the unshift() function. The return of the function tells me that there are 4 items but the data isn't inside the array.

It looks like this :

```
var listeLiens = [{
    titre: "So Foot",
    url: "http://sofoot.com",
    auteur: "yann.usaille"
  },
  {
    titre: "Guide d'autodéfense numérique",
    url: "http://guide.boum.org",
    auteur: "paulochon"
  },
  {
    titre: "L'encyclopédie en ligne Wikipedia",
    url: "http://Wikipedia.org",
    auteur: "annie.zette"
  }
];

inputSubmit.addEventListener("click", function() {
  form = document.querySelector("form");
  listeLiens.unshift({
    "titre": form.elements.titreLien.value,
    "url": form.elements.urlLien.value,
    "auteur": form.elements.nomAuteur.value
  });
});
```

I checked on the web but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Could you please explain your question further, it is difficult to understand.

Comment: Looks alright to me, see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t6vLu139/1/
The console logs 4 items in the array. I would suggest using the submit event on the form instead of click event on the button.

Comment: "*but the datas are not added to the array.*" - why do you think that? Where (and especially when) are you using the array?

Comment: Working fine for me. No issues with the code.

Comment: `I checked on the web but couldn't find a solution` to what? There's no problem.  The solution is, "there's no problem".  Check the web for this comment and you'll find your solution ;)

Comment: The array is declared at the beginning of my script and I'm trying to modify it with the unshift() function inside the click event, my mistake is maybe about the kind of the event as Meldon as suggested...

Comment: I just tried changing the event for submit but the same thing happens. No datas added in the array !

Answer (score 0):

I tried some things to solve the problem but it stills the same mistake !
I don't suceed in accessing to the global array declared at the beginning of my script in my event... it seems to be another array used in the event, not the same as at the beggining of the script...